# Set available status for teams user with power automate flow

Tags: httprequest, microsoft-teams, azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I am trying to set status available for my user with power automate flow, but everytime I close teams window user is set up to offline status.
It is possible to set available status to never change from available ?
I am using "Send an HTTP request to SharePoint" with configuration ->

```
Site address: url link
Method: PUT
Uri: /v1/me/forceavailability/
Headers: content-type application/json
```

JSON Body ->

```
{
  "availability": "Availlable",
  "desiredExpirationTime": "2021-08-29T14:29:01.834Z"
}
```

Comment: Whenever you set the preferred availability and activity status for a user, Preferred presence takes effect only when there is at least one presence session of the user. Otherwise, the user's presence stays as Offline - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-setuserpreferredpresence?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http.

So it is by design behavior. If you close Teams window status will be set to offline.

Answer (score 0):

In Office portal open Outlook web app, go to calendar and create "all day" meeting, set day from - day to and busy status in meeting configuration.
Then if you work with SharePoint HTTP request on Logic Apps/Automate Flow set in http request status for user as "available"

```
{
  "availability": "Availlable",
  "desiredExpirationTime": "2021-08-29T14:29:01.834Z"
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).